# CodeIgniter: How to get Controller, Action, URL information

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have these URLs:

- http://backend.domain.com/system/setting/edit/12
- http://backend.domain.com/product/edit/1

How to get controller name, action name from these URLs. I'm CodeIgniter newbie. Are there any helper function to get this info

Ex:

```php
$params = helper_function( current_url() )
```

Where `$params` becomes something like

```php
array (
  'controller' => 'system/settings', 
  'action' => 'edit', 
  '...'=>'...'
)
```

Answer (score 227, accepted):

You could use the [URI Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html):

```
$this->uri->segment(n); // n=1 for controller, n=2 for method, etc
```

I've also been told that the following work, but am currently unable to test:

```
$this->router->fetch_class();
$this->router->fetch_method();
```

Comment: because my controller have sub folder, so $this->uri->segment(1) return controller name maybe incorrect. Thanks for your help, I use $this->router to get the informations.

Comment: For getting the Directory Correctly you can also use:
 $this->router->fetch_directory();

Comment: Hey if you are using Codeigniter 3, then for Controller use: $this->router->class;  for Method: $this->router->method; for Directory: $this->router->directory; Documentation: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html#uri-routing-methods-fetch-directory-fetch-class-fetch-method

Comment: $this->router->fetch_class();
$this->router->fetch_method();
it works.

Answer (score 137):

Instead of using URI segments you should do this:

```
$this->router->fetch_class(); // class = controller
$this->router->fetch_method();
```

That way you know you are always using the correct values even if you are behind a routed URL, in a sub-domain, etc.

Comment: I just found out, that using this method, you cannot get correct class method name when calling a view like `modules::run('module/controller/action')`. It just shows the router information of the loaded page. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: Awesome! Any word on how secure this is? I.e. can this be spoofed?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - or using the shortcut: $this->router->class

Comment: Not if you change the routes in routes.php, `$this->router` returns the class the code runs in, but not the actual router masked with the override. Both answers are quite useful based on what you want to do.

Comment: These methods have been depricated, use `$this->router->class` and  `$this->router->method` instead

Answer (score 35):

The methods are deprecated.

```
$this->router->fetch_class();
$this->router->fetch_method();
```

You can access the properties instead.

```
$this->router->class;
$this->router->method;
```

See [codeigniter user guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html?highlight=ci_router)

> ## URI Routing methods fetch_directory(), fetch_class(), fetch_method()
>
> With properties `CI_Router::$directory`, `CI_Router::$class` and
>   `CI_Router::$method` being public and their respective `fetch_*()` no
>   longer doing anything else to just return the properties - it doesn’t
>   make sense to keep them.
>
> Those are all internal, undocumented methods, but we’ve opted to
>   deprecate them for now in order to maintain backwards-compatibility
>   just in case. If some of you have utilized them, then you can now just
>   access the properties instead:
>
> ```
> $this->router->directory;
> $this->router->class;
> $this->router->method;
> ```

Answer (score 12):

Another way

```
$this->router->class
```

Answer (score 11):

As an addition

```
$this -> router -> fetch_module(); //Module Name if you are using HMVC Component
```

Comment: This `fetch_module()` call doesn't work for me in CI 2.1.2. Can't find it in the /system/router.php file.

Comment: @timpeterson, It is only available in HMVC component as told in the answer.

Answer (score 8):

**Update**

The answer was added was in 2015 and the following methods are deprecated now

```
$this->router->fetch_class();  in favour of  $this->router->class; 
$this->router->fetch_method(); in favour of  $this->router->method;
```

---

Hi you should use the following approach

```
$this->router->fetch_class(); // class = controller
$this->router->fetch_method(); // action
```

for this purpose but for using this you need to extend your hook from the `CI_Controller` and it works like a charm, you should not use uri segments

Answer (score 3):

If you using $this->uri->segment ,  if urls rewriting rules change, segments name matching will be lost.

Answer (score 3):

**Use This Code anywhere in class or libraries**

```
    $current_url =& get_instance(); //  get a reference to CodeIgniter
    $current_url->router->fetch_class(); // for Class name or controller
    $current_url->router->fetch_method(); // for method name
```

Answer (score 1):

Last segment of URL will always be the action. Please get like this:

```
$this->uri->segment('last_segment');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->router->fetch_class();
```

// fecth class the class in controller
    $this->router->fetch_method();

// method

Answer (score -4):

controller class is not working any functions.

so I recommend to you use the following scripts

```
global $argv;

if(is_array($argv)){
    $action = $argv[1];
    $method = $argv[2];
}else{
    $request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $pattern = "/.*?\/index\.php\/(.*?)\/(.*?)$/";
    preg_match($pattern, $request_uri, $params);
    $action = $params[1];
    $method = $params[2];
}
```

Comment: There are predefined functions available like $this->router->fetch_class() and fetch_method() then we don't need to do manually.