# How to access the params given to the controllers by the routing system within a hook in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook, url-routing, codeigniter-2

I want to log the requests that my app receive using a `post_controller_constructor` hook.

The hook's code below illustrate what I need:

```php
public function log() {
  $controller = $this->router->fetch_class();
  $action = $this->router->fetch_method();

  $post_params = $this->input->post();
  $get_params = $this->input->get();

  $url_params = ???;
...
  $this->log_model->log($id_user, $controller, $action, time(), $post_params, $get_params, $url_params);
}

function __get($key){
  $CI =& get_instance();
  return $CI->$key;
}
```

For what I saw, the solution has to be related with 'URI' Class and the segments extracted from there.
But I cannot rely on this aproach because I have that some controllers are deeper than others like this examples:

- `/folder/set_controllers/controller_a/action/(:any)`
  `/folder/set_controllers/controller_a/action/7` the value for `$url_params` is `array('7')`.
- `/folder/controller_b/action/(:any)/(:any)`
  `/folder/controller_b/action/first_param/second_param/7` the value for `$url_params` is `array('first_param', 'second_param')`.
- `/controller_c/action/(:any)`
  `/controller_c/action/hello` the value for `$url_params` is `array('hello')`.

And I need to know what values `$url_params` have.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the answer of this question can help you [How to get Controller, Action, URL informations with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062086/how-to-get-controller-action-url-informations-with-codeigniter) it looks you are looking for the same, more or less.