# How get the current view name in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How get the name of the current displaying view for pass to another function?

Comment: please explain your question more and if possible provide some code

Answer (score 13):

If you want to display view name within view :

```
echo $_ci_view;
```

Also see  `print_r(get_defined_vars())` you will see many interesting variables from CI.

Comment: Does not work anymore in CodeIgniter 4 and up.

Answer (score 3):

You could pass the name of the View to the View.

Controller:

```
$data = array('viewName' => 'home_view');
$this->load->view($data['viewName'], $data);
```

Then to access in your view you could retrieve the view name with:

```
<?php echo $viewName ?>
//produces 'home_view'
```

Comment: This is the best answer.  Another simple solution: Do it manually by setting a variable $viewName in your view (soooo obvious) , or get it from the filename,  like this: `basename(__FILE__, '.php')`. 
Note: $_ci_view does not exist in CodeIgniter 4, neither does $this->router .

Answer (score 2):

> How get the name of the current displaying view?

```
$thisFile = pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$thisViewName = trim($thisFile, '.php');
echo $thisFile; // view_filename.php
echo $thisViewName; // view_filename
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a way to fetch the view. The closest you can do is to fetch the action and controller being routed to.

You can use the Router class provided by CodeIgniter to achieve this. Use

```
$this->router->fetch_method();
```

to get the current action.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2062141/393021)

Comment: Does not work anymore in CodeIgniter 4 and up.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use PHP, within the view `someview.php` write this:

```
<?php echo basename(__FILE__, ".php"); ?> //prints: someview
```

Others suggested `<?=$_ci_view?>` beware that it will print out the entire file name of the view: `someview.php` and not just the view name `someview`

Answer (score -1):

For those needing to know the current class name, you can use this command within the view to get its parent class:

```
<?= $this->router->class ?>
```

For the current view use:

```
<?= $_ci_view; ?>
```

Comment: Does not work anymore in CodeIgniter 4 and up.