# Codeigniter can't use this->uri->segment(3) as value in function

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

Why this code is ok

```
$this->sch_teacher_id = $this->ion_auth->user_by_username("vika")->row()->id;
```

But this doesn't work?

```
$this->sch_teacher_id = $this->ion_auth->user_by_username($this->uri->segment(3))->row()->id;
```

My url is domain:8888/admin_schedule/teacher/vika

route.php contains

```
$route['admin_schedule/teacher/(:any)'] = "admin_schedule/index/$1";
```

I use code lines in **function __construct()**, and the result of it use in another controller function, because 3 functions use this result. If I move this code in one of this functions and use **$this->uri->segment(3)** then I get not 'vika's lessons, but *my own lessons*, so

```
public function user_by_username($username = FALSE)
    {
        $this->trigger_events('user');

        //if no id was passed use the current users id
        $username || $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

        $this->limit(1);
        $this->where($this->tables['users'].'.username', $username);

        $this->users();

        return $this;
    }
```

works good. But $this->uri->segment(3) if use it as parameter in user_by_username function, doesn't work!

page generated next way:
controller admin_schedule have function index which render view index.php.
And in that view I use javascript, that call another function from admin_schedule controller = get_schedule_db_recurring_events_on_daysweek such way:

```
...
{
                url: '/admin_schedule/get_schedule_db_recurring_events_on_daysweek/',//"<?echo $data_path?>",
                backgroundColor: 'red',
            }
```

and in controller

```
function get_schedule_db_recurring_events_on_daysweek()
    {   
        $start = date('Y-m-d H:i', $this->input->get('start')); 
        $end = date('Y-m-d H:i', $this->input->get('end')); 
        $sch_teacher_id = $this->uri->segment(3); // <--- this doesn't work, but $sch_teacher_id = 111 works perfectly
        $result=$this->Schedule_model->get_schedule_recurring_events_on_daysweek($start, $end, $sch_teacher_id);
        $count=count($result);      
        if($count>0){
                echo json_encode($result);
        }
    }
```

Please, help understand this problem.

Comment: Have you tried to assign this to a variable and echo it to see what is going on?

Comment: yes, of course: $username1 = "'".$this->uri->segment(3)."'";
  print_r($username1); This print 'vika' as it should.

Comment: If so, your last question is already answered. This left us with the main problem. Have you tried to pass this value with a variable instead of directly to the method (seems weird but it causes some trouble with references in some cases). Just a try.

Comment: Passing value 'vika' in variable $username1 = "vika"; gives good result, yes. Problem happened if I use $this->uri->segment(3). I've tried rsegment instead segment and it doesn't help.

Comment: If you solved your problem, post the solution as an answer, so it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember the reason - it's just CI quirk you have learn to accept - you can't use $this->uri->segment(3) etc as an argument directly, you will need to assign it and then pass that as @almix suggested for his sanity test.

At-least I have also always had trouble using it directly as an argument - tho I will be happy for anyone to correct me!

Comment: No, Brian, assigning it to argument doesn't work too. $sch_teacher_id = 111;//$this->uri->segment(3);
  $result=$this->Schedule_model->get_schedule_recurring_events_on_daysweek($start, $end, $sch_teacher_id); works, but with $sch_teacher_id = $this->uri->segment(3); doesn't!

Comment: you mean: $username1 = $this->uri->segment(3); then using $username1 does'nt work?

Comment: Hmmm ok http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html states that it will return 'false' if the item is not found.

Comment: I add explaination about route in question.

Comment: may be somehow use this advise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062086/how-to-get-controller-action-url-informations-with-codeigniter#2071176

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem!

Think that something goes wrong because of ajax calls. So when I code in controller

```
function __construct()
 {
        parent::__construct();
        ...

        $this->sch_teacher_row = $this->ion_auth->user_by_username($this->uri->segment(3))->row();
        $this->data['sch_teacher_id'] = $this->sch_teacher_row->id;
        $this->data['subtitle'] = $this->sch_teacher_row->username;          
 }
```

Next I have the right value ('vika'), or to be more precise vika's id ('911') in **view file** but not in other function of my controller. But I can pass this value now (sch_teacher_id) from the view to this controller with jQuery $.ajax option **data**:

```
eventSources: [
...         
{
                url: '/admin_schedule/get_schedule_db_recurring_events_on_daysweek/',//"<?echo $data_path?>",
                type: 'GET',
                data: {sch_teacher_id: sch_teacher_id},
                backgroundColor: 'red',
            }  
        ],
```

And next (on the other side of the mountain) catch this GET parameter and kick it to the model function:

```
function get_schedule_db_recurring_events_on_daysweek()
    {   
        ...
        $sch_teacher_id_from_view = $this->input->get('sch_teacher_id');
        $result=$this->Schedule_model->get_schedule_recurring_events_on_daysweek($start, $end, $sch_teacher_id_from_view);
        ...
    }
```

And it is all the breakdance.

Comment: This is the same as our suggestion to assign it then pass it.