# Know controller name in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

For my Codeigniter (v 3.1.7) project, i create debug menu (like prestashop) with all informations of the login user, error of the page... to debug quickly the page.

So, i want to call the name of the controller and the name of the function.
If i'm on the page "login" i want to display:

```
Controller: Account
Function: Login
```

I find on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062086/how-to-get-controller-action-url-informations-with-codeigniter) i tips for my problem but we use Url REWRITING and the name of the url is not the real name of the controller.

Comment: What about the `__CLASS__` php keyword?

`echo __CLASS__; //MyController`

Comment: Take look at `route.php` which place in `application/config` all routes defined there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Controller, Action, URL informations with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062086/how-to-get-controller-action-url-informations-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your CI version is below 3, you have to use like that:

```
$this->router->fetch_class();
$this->router->fetch_method();
```

and if your CI version is 3 or above. These methods are deprecated.

```
$this->router->fetch_class();
$this->router->fetch_method();
```

You can access the properties instead.

```
$this->router->class;
$this->router->method;
```

See [codeigniter user guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html?highlight=ci_router)

URI Routing methods fetch_directory(), fetch_class(), fetch_method()
With properties CI_Router::$directory, CI_Router::$class and CI_Router::$method being public and their respective fetch_*() no longer doing anything else to just return the properties - it doesn’t make sense to keep them.

Those are all internal, undocumented methods, but we’ve opted to deprecate them for now in order to maintain backwards-compatibility just in case. If some of you have utilized them, then you can now just access the properties instead:

```
$this->router->directory;
$this->router->class;
$this->router->method;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the URI Class to get that information:

```
$this->uri->segment(n); // n=1 for controller, n=2 for method, etc
```